# Facebook Messenger Dialog callback doesnt' work

Tags: android, facebook, onactivityresult, facebook-messenger

I have implemented the new Facebook Messenger Dialog in my app to sent "Invites":

```
builder = new FacebookDialog.MessageDialogBuilder(getActivity())
        .setLink("http://demo.fivestarday.se/tidningsklippet/index.html")
        .setName("Inbjudan till Tidningsklippet")
        .setCaption("Inbjudan till Tidningsklippet")
        .setDescription("Du har blivit inbjuden till tidningsklippet med inbjudningskod:")      
        .setFragment(this);
```

...

```
FacebookDialog dialog = builder.build();
                    dialog.present();
```

This works as expected and the Facebook Messenger app is shown and lets the user send a message.

However when I want to catch the callback in:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data) {
                Log.e("Activity", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
                Log.i("Activity", "Success!");
            }
        });
```

the `onError` or the onComplete is not called and I dont know if the user canceled the request or sent it. `onActivityResult` is called however.

Earlier in my `Fragment` I have registered a `UiLifeCycleHelper`

```
uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), null);
uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Has anyone completed this task for Android with Messenger dialog? Or is this another Facebook bug?

**UPDATE**

After reporting this issue to Facebook I got the same answer as from atablash below. However  you wont be able to get the completion gesture when using the Messenger Dialog unless the user have authed your app (logged in). In my app the user doesn't do that because the Messenger Dialog does not require that. So basically if you want to use the Messenger Dialog and get a callback you have to force the user to lag in first.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall( dialog.present() )` when presenting the dialog.

See here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share/
(Sharing a link using the Share Dialog, Step 2)

Comment: Hi Yes you are correct, this must be done. The problem is that when you get the callback you cannot fetch the completionGesture because the user haven't authed the app. So this question doesnt have an answer